# Database images in SSRS 2005

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-grouping

I have an image stored in my database that is going to dynamically change between pages.  However, what seems to be happening is that it takes the first image it runs into, and repeats it across all pages.  Has anyone else ran into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used dynamic images before but haven't had this issue - though my images were not in a database.

What are you using for the Value of the image?

Is your image in a table so it goes through the dataset records? If your image isn't part of a table, it won't know to select different images. For instance, if I was showing a report of employees and had an avatar image of each employee, I would have the database image field as part of the query. The image would be inside the table and reference the image field. The image would change as the employee grouping changed from one person to the next.

If your paging isn't determined by something in your dataset, you'll have to come up with some logic to calculate which picture to show and when - probably using the global page number - **Globals!PageNumber**. That might be tricky with them in a table though.

Comment: The image is stored as part of the dataset. It is base64 encoded.  The paging is done based off a group that contains my details that works correctly outside of the image.

Comment: This wasn't exactly the answer to fix my problems but it did point me to reviewing my selection criteria.  I had made an amateur mistake that led to the wrong image being displayed. Thanks